# Animation not transitioning Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, unityscript

so I’m kind of new to Unity and I’m making a top down 2D shooting game. I’m trying to make my character play the death animation when he dies but for some reason it doesn’t transition. I tried using the Float condition and Bool condition in the animator but both don’t work when I set the float/bool to 1/true with animator.SetBool/SetFloat. The strangest thing is that if even when I put the bool to true or float to 1 in the animator it doesn’t work either and doesn’t change the animation. I’m probably overlooking 1 little thing so I hope you can explain. (btw my code is kinda spaghetti i know)

Animator Picture 1:
image
image
1056×419 21.2 KB

Animator Picture 2:
image
image
418×673 22.7 KB

Animator component on player object:
image
Script (although maybe not really necessary because it doesn’t work in the editor either)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Weapon weapon;
    public Camera sceneCamera;
    public float moveSpeed;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 moveDirection;
    private Vector2 mousePosition;
    public GameObject enemy;
    public float health = 5f;
    public GameObject player;
    public Image healthImage;
    public float gunTurnSpeed = 5f;
    public Transform gunTransform;
    public Animator animator;
    private float isDead = 0f;

    void FixedUpdate(){
       Move();
    }

    void ProcessInputs(){
        float moveX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float moveY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){

            weapon.Fire();
        }

        moveDirection = new Vector2(moveX, moveY).normalized;
        mousePosition = sceneCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        
    }

    void Move(){
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveDirection.x * moveSpeed, moveDirection.y * moveSpeed );

        Vector2 aimDirection = mousePosition - rb.position;
        float aimAngle = Mathf.Atan2(aimDirection.y, aimDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
        
    }
    public void TakeDamage()
    {
        healthImage.fillAmount = health / 5f;
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("enemy"))
        {
            health -= 1;
            TakeDamage();
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {
        animator.SetFloat("isDead", isDead);
        ProcessInputs();

        if (health <= 0)
        {
            isDead = 1f;
            SceneManager.LoadScene("gameoverscene");
            Cursor.visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well setting is dead every frame is hopefully unnecessary and would be false for the whole game until the if health<=0 section.. where you load a scene and the animation wouildnt have time to play anyway.. so.

Comment: If you're going to repost your Unity forum question here, at the very least take them time to also post the relevant pictures.